# real time analytics for iOS works for ipa only

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using Google analytics version 3.14.0 for iOS 9.1.  When I build my app through Xcode and run on a device, realtime analytics are not reported.  When I build an ipa, install on device and run it, it reports real time analytics.  Can I control that programmatically instead?  developers would love to verify analytics as they make changes (at least more easily check them).

I have reviewed similar questions here.  I have taken those questions and answers in to account.  The analytics account works fine when installed as an ipa.  I have decreased the interval time for reporting to 1 second.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:I haven't actually verified this.

What I'm guessing is happening is that Google Analytics is conditionally sending metrics to the server based on the Release Configuration.  Since you have identified that archived IPAs successfully report the metrics, but debug builds to device don't, try changing the Release Configuration for Runs to Release.

Open the Scheme editor for the project (Command-Shift-,) and specify Release for the Build Configuration:

[image]

Then build and run from Xcode onto a device (or simulator even) and see if the analytics are reported.  Might as well keep that interval at 1 second as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I have tried using both the release build and debug build settings.  Changing the build configuration does not cause the realtime analytics to be reported.  I have verified that generating an ipa with debug or release configuration does generate realtime analytics.